# Windows Driver Development with Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, driver, wdk

Is that possible to integrate WDK into Eclipse? WDK seems to have its own compiler and debugger, so I wonder if there is a plug-in or it could be done manually?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953568/setting-up-eclipse-for-windows-driver-development/11754808#11754808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See DDKBUILD for an example of how to launch the WDK build procedure from a bath file:

http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=43

Typically all you need to do is modify this procedure to fit your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Eclipse from build environment that you need (free or checked with needed architecture)
2. Create project or import C/C++ / Existing code as makefile project. Select GNU Toolchain.
3. Properties -> Builders -> New -> Environment -> Select, select all variables, mark "add to all configurations", select "replace native environment with specified on". On the Main tab select full path to build.exe of the selected build environment. Select your project directory in workspace as "working directory"
4. Properties -> C/C++ Build -> On Bulder Settings tab remove "Use default build command" flag and type "build"
5. Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor -> Select Tools. Personaly I selected msvc compilers.
6. Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> select includes that you need including WDK ones
7. Enjoy